# Struggle to click on a ''Ok'' button with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, button

I tried to click on a "Ok" Button with selenium and it simply doesn't work.. I am able to click on any other button except this one. Here is the class:

```
<button class="button-1iktpaT1 size-l-2NEs9_xt intent-primary-1-IOYcbg appearance-default-dMjF_2Hu actionButton-3wPv1Zy2 small-3wPv1Zy2" name="ok"><span class="content-2PGssb8d"><span class="">Ok</span></span></button>
```

I tried with this :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span/span[contains(text(),\'Ok\')]/parent::button').click()
```

It works with others buttons.. Anyone have the solution? thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you simply do it with the name provided like this: `self.driver.find_element_by_name('ok').click()`

Comment: Is your "OK" button is in `iframe`? If it is in `iframe` then you have to shift to that `iframe` and then search and perform operation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `xpath` `//button[@name='ok']`

Answer (score 1):

Easy Peezy:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name('ok')
```

OR

```
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[name="ok"]')
```

It's better to search by the id, name, or class of an element than the text when possible.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using different 'searching' methods like

> `self.driver.find_element_by_name`
> or
> `self.driver.find_element_by_class`
> or
> `self.driver.find_element_by_id`

With one of these methods you should be able to click the button.